# Wrong behavior when click on item in recyclerView to change its color?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, recyclerview-layout

I'm trying to change the background color of the clicked item in RecyclerView from the adapter and it works,  but the problem is when I click on position 1 it changes the color of position 1 and 7, and when I click on position 2 it changes the color of position 2 and 8 and so on ...

```
public class RecyclerViewAdapter extends 
RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewAdapter.viewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<String> name = new ArrayList<>();
    private Context context;
    boolean added = false;

    public RecyclerViewAdapter(ArrayList<String> name, Context context) {
        this.name = name;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public viewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_horizontal_listview, parent, false);

        return new viewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final viewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.cardView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {

                final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(view.getContext());
                dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                dialog.setCancelable(false);
                dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_item_dialog_small);
                Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                window.setLayout(500, 450);

                Button addToList = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addToList);
                addToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {

                        holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.layer4);

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });

                dialog.show();

            }
        });

}
```

Edit:
here is the cardView :

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/cardView"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="320dp"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@color/layer2"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="2dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linear"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="2dp"
        android:background="@color/layer3"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewItemName"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Test Item"
                android:textColor="@color/add_button"
                android:textSize="25sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:padding="5dp">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/item_number"
                android:textColor="@color/text_view_color"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textViewItemNumber"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:textColor="@color/second_color"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: post cardview xml code

Comment: posted ! Omi   it is simple somehow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of implementing options (such as favorite icon, checkbox, highlight or ...) to each row of a recyclerview, i think the best way is to create an object with your arbitrary parameter. for example for favorite a `boolean` parameter is best choice.

In your case you should create an object with a string and a boolean parameter with their setters and getters like below:

```
public class mObject {
   private String name;
   private boolean clicked;

        // setters and getters
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        public boolean isClicked() {
            return clicked;
        }

        public void setClicked(boolean clicked) {
            this.clicked = clicked;
        }
}
```

and then set your data in a list of this object then pass it to the adapter.
In `onBindViewHolder`, first check click value, if is true change the color. then in `onClick` method do both change the boolean value and background color and finally use `notifyDataSetChanged();` for updating view.
Your adapter  `onBindViewHolder` should looks like below:

```
@Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.ViewHolder view,final int position) {

            final MVH holder = (MVH) view;
            holder.tv.setText(name.get(position).getName());

            if (name.get(position).isClicked()){
                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            } else {
                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            }
            holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {

                    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(context);
                    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                    dialog.setCancelable(false);
                    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.add_item_dialog_small);
                    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
                    window.setLayout(500, 450);
                    Button addToList = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.addToList);
                    addToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {

                            if (name.get(position).isClicked()){
                                name.get(position).setClicked(false);
                                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
                            } else {
                                name.get(position).setClicked(true);
                                holder.tv.setBackgroundColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
                            }
                            dialog.dismiss();
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    });

                    dialog.show();

                }
            });
        }
```

Comment: @SundosAltamimi Whats the problem? this worked on my device.

Comment: I put the if statement in at the top of onBindView and it worked ,, Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can simplyfy your code using lambdas, that's for sure.

This:

```
addToList.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @SuppressLint("ResourceAsColor")
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.layer4);

                }
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
```

You can change to:

```
addToList.setOnClickListener((View v) -> {

                        holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.layer4);

                    }
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

store var positionClicked in your adapter so it will be

```
onClick{positionClicked = position)
```

and then in your onBindViewHolder put

```
if(positionClicked==position){
  //change color of element here// 
}
```

Comment: but how to get the position in adapter? I mean I get the position from within the onBindViewHolder  only !!

Comment: you put both snips of code in "onBindViewHolder"  -there U have posiiton...get it?

Comment: got it , the problem is it recycling the item with its background color when scroll it away , I think it is not matter of position :/

Comment: yeah , exacly it is the same element  but bc it is recyclerview it seams to highlight two elements- by storing position U will be able to style element depending on  position in array and not depending on viewHolder(which can be recycled) - let me know if U made it to work(y)

Comment: can you please show it in answer , Im getting confused of this but it seems like you are confident of it

Answer (score 0):

I face this problem also. What you can do is set the background colour before click in onBindViewHolder method.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final viewHolder holder, final int position) {

holder.cardView.setBackgroundColor(R.color.defaultBackgroundColour);
```